# Opening Multiple Modals freeze the screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web-deployment, web-frontend

I have like 12 Modals on a webpage,
I am opening a modal from  tag which has data-modal and data target as follows:

```
<a data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#services1_modal"  class="preview-link" title="More Details"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
<a data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#services2_modal" class="details-link" title="Pricing"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
<a data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#services3_modal" class="details-link" title="Pricing"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
<a data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#services4_modal" class="details-link" title="Pricing"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
<a data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#services5_modal" class="details-link" title="Pricing"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
```

and the modal I am targeting as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade services1_modal" id="services1_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
<div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
 <div class="modal-content ">
   <div class="modal-body" >
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

and the same thing I am doing for each modal with changing its class and the id to match with the data target.

The first two modals are working fine, but the others when I am clicking on the link for them, it freezing my screen and I have to refresh the page.

What the issue seems to be in this?

Comment: The Twitter Bootstrap [documentation about modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) says: _"Bootstrap only supports one modal window at a time. Nested modals aren’t supported as we believe them to be poor user experiences."_. It is possible you're using something to support multiple modals, but then you have to mention that.

Comment: I am opening one model each time,

Comment: OK, sorry, I didn't get that from your question.

Comment: Well, I can't tell from your question what the problem is. My best guess is that what you call: "freezing my screen", has to to with some DOM element staying on top blocking access. You can find out which one that is by using the inspector in your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools).